# Elegant way to limit possible values of string property

Tags: vb.net, properties

I'm looking for a cleaner way than what I'm about to present to limit the possible values of a string property.  Suppose I have a class with a property "Direction"

```
Public Class Location
    Private _Direction As String
    Public Property Direction() As String
        Get
            Return _Direction
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Direction = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

So suppose I want to limit the possible values of direction to "North," "South," "East," and "West."  I realize I could do something like this:

```
Public Class Location
    Private ValidDirection As New Collection
    Public Sub New
        ValidDirection.Add("1", "North")
        ...
    End Sub
    Private _Direction As String
    Public Property Direction() As String
        Get
            Return _Direction
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If Me.ValidDirection.Contains(value) Then
                _Direction = value
            Else
                Throw New Exception("Invalid direction.")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

But if I happen to create lots of `Location`s then I've created that collection over and over again.  For this example it's not such a big deal, but suppose I have 25 possibilities for 5 or more properties and I create hundreds or thousands of `Location`s, then it starts to add up.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

I should also note, just in case it complicates things, that I'd like to translate the input into the accepted value in certain cases.  For example, "N" is used and I'd like to automatically turn that into "North."

Any ideas?

Comment: define one or more Enums and most of the validation code can go away - if the Direction prop is `As myEnum` no validation needed.  for the string representation, you can use `enumDirection.Tostring`

Comment: Ah, I was aware of `.ToString` but did not realize it worked that way with Enums.  Thank you.  I suspected Enums were the way to achieve this, but I could not get past not using a numeric value.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by Plutonix, you should be defining an enumeration:

```
Public Enum Direction
    North
    South
    East
    West
End Enum
```

You now declare your property as that type.  You will almost certainly have already used a number of enumerations, e.g. the `DialogResult` returned by `ShowDialog` and a number of them used by `MessageBox.Show`.  There are also a number that you may have used in the WinForms designer, e.g. for the `Dock` and `Anchor` properties of forms and controls, the `Style` property of a `ProgressBar` and the `DropDownStyle` of a `ComboBox`.

Note that the values are represented by numbers under the hood - `Integer` values starting at zero by default - and the result of calling `ToString` will give you the name.  If you need something other than the name, e.g. you need to include spaces, then you can apply the `Description` attribute and write some simple code to get that.